# MySQL Group By get title column with smallest date value

Tags: mysql, group-by, row, aggregate-functions

I have a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY sid
ORDER BY datestart desc
LIMIT 10
```

which returns the last 10 sid groups.

For each of these groups, I need the title column of the row with the lowest datestart value

I tried using

```
SELECT *, min(datestart)
```

but that didn't return the row with the smallest datestart value, just the lowest datestart. I need the **title** from the lowest datestart.

(Relevant) Table Structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `datestart` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sid` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `datestart` (`datestart`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post you table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer

```
select t1.* from `table` as t1
inner join (
select sid,min(datestart) as elder
from `table`
group by sid
order by elder desc limit 10) as t2
on t1.sid = t2.sid and t1.datestart = t2.elder
```

Use a composite index on (sid,datestart)

Comment: What's the benefit of using a composite index over having two indexes?

Comment: This query will be much faster if you use a composite index specifing fields in that particular order. Order of fields within index is also very important.

Comment: Is there a reason why the "order by datestart desc limit 10" is outside of the subquery? Instead of the query searching through the entire table, I want it to stop after finding 10 sid groups that match if possible. Would putting that code in the subquery make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. You will get expected results. If it don't work change `Table_2.datestart > Table_1.datestart` by `Table_2.datestart < Table_1.datestart`

```
SELECT title, datestart
FROM `table` AS Table_1
LEFT JOIN `table` AS Table_2 ON (Table_2.sid = Table_1.sid AND Table_2.datestart > Table_1.datestart)
Table_2.sid IS NULL;
```

---

Edited query

```
SELECT Table_1.title, Table_1.datestart
FROM `table` AS Table_1
LEFT JOIN `table` AS Table_2 ON (Table_2.sid = Table_1.sid AND Table_2.datestart > Table_1.datestart)
Table_2.sid IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm getting errors in the query (path in field list in ambiguous)

Comment: Yep sure… i forget… `SELECT Table_1.title, Table_1.datestart`

Comment: Hmm, it still didn't return the right answer. But nick rulez provided a query that works. Thank you anyways sir!

Comment: Stange I'm always using this structure because it don't use subquery and it's faster… But if you have result that you expect, don't change anything

Comment: Also, I think this query would assume there's only one other row with a lower date value. The min() function would help find the smallest date value