# MySQL - Group By one column and get the lowest value

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to return the lowest value for every set of data grouped by a column.

In English, I want to arrange my data into groups by accommodation but only return the lowest perperson price for each accommodation.

I found a similar example (my attempt with it below) at [MySQL Group By get title column with smallest date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697442/mysql-group-by-get-title-column-with-smallest-date-value)

---

```
SELECT t1 . * FROM tbl_TravelFeed AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT pk_id, MIN( perperson ) AS perperson FROM tbl_TravelFeed
        GROUP BY accommodation
        ORDER BY perperson) AS t2    
   ON t1.pk_id = t2.pk_id AND t1.perperson = t2.perperson
```

---

This seems to almost work, but it returns a record by lowest ID instead of perperson. I can't understand why to be able to correct it.

I am trying to finish a university assignment for Tuesday (27th March '12) and would love to get this working properly but it is non-critical in the bigger picture.

I have tried many ways of doing this including use of Distinct. The above query seems to have got closest to it.

Would be very grateful for any help.

Aaron

Comment: @Cfreak Why remove the homework tag? OP states this is a university assignment.

Comment: @jzworkman if I did it was accidental. I was attempting to cleanup the query

Answer (score 2):

This is untested but this is how I would write it in MySQL, you the reason I put my subquery in the WHERE statement is so that I could easily create a VIEW from this query and always keep the results stored in a separate view so I could make queries against that.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Travelfeed AS t
WHERE perperson =
(
  SELECT MIN(perperson)
  FROM tbl_Travelfeed
  WHERE accommodation = t.accommodation
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.  Since you are grouping by accommodation, the appropriate link from the inner table and the outer table is the `accommodation` field, not `pk_id`:

```
(SELECT accommodation, MIN( perperson ) AS perperson FROM tbl_TravelFeed
    GROUP BY accommodation
    ORDER BY perperson) AS t2
ON t1.**accommodation** = t2.**accommodation** AND t1.perperson = t2.perperson
```

Comment: This is very close thanks you. Just need to handle the situations where there are multiple records with the same lowest value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM 
        tbl_TravelFeed AS t
    INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT accommodation
               , MIN(perperson) AS perperson 
          FROM tbl_TravelFeed
          GROUP BY accommodation
        ) AS g 
      ON  g.accommodation = t.accommodation
      AND g.perperson = t.perperson
```